# Service bus broker stuck in starting

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

I have a standalone server with workflow manager that suddenly stopped working!!!

I checked the service bus in services and noted

The service bus message broker can't start and its status is starting!

What is the issue cause, How can solve this issue?

Comment: check the event log (application, system & setup for more clue)

Comment: Unexpected error

Comment: could you please check event log > Application and Services logs > Microsoft-Service Bus > now check all (admin, Operational, debug and analytic). share the complete error detail

Comment: Check this **[Service Bus Message Broker Stuck on Starting](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/service-bus-message-broker-stuck-on-starting/)**